# ffmpeg command line to c++ conversion

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I currently involved in a project of real time video transmission. Recently I touched ffmpeg but still very nooby. I notice the ffmpeg command line is very powerful and the functions are just what I want. Here is a file of ffmpeg command line of performing real time video transmission.
http://www.wu.ece.ufl.edu/projects/wirelessVideo/project/realTimeCoding/download/doc/howto.pdf
Can anyone advise how can I get the corresponding c++ code for these command line? I want to do a c++ program to realize these functions.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `execve` (or some other member of the `exec*()` family of system library calls) to run `ffmpeg` in a subprocess.

Comment: sorry for the late reply pro, could u please give me any example how that works? I totally have no idea.....

Comment: Take a look at [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/downloads.html), Chapter 3; read through to the section "Using fork and exec together". (The "spawn" function.) It's not the book I'd recommend reading if you were going to buy a book -- I'd go for Richard Stevens' Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment -- but for free, it's seems acceptable.